# MIPS assembly calculating hypotenuse

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a MIPS program to compute the hypotenuse from two integers. However the program prints some weird number not the actual result, my best guess is there is something wrong with the square root function.

```
    .data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter value for A: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter value for B: "
result:  .asciiz "The hypotenuse is: "

    .text
main:
         # save $ra
         addi $sp, $sp, -4
         sw $ra, 0($sp)

         # accept input
         la $a0, prompt1
         addi $v0, $0, 4         # Print prompt1 string
         syscall
         addi $v0, $0, 6         # Read float
         syscall
         add.s $f12, $f5, $f0     # f12 = A(input float)

         la $a0, prompt2
         addi $v0, $0, 4         # Print prompt2 string
         syscall
         addi $v0, $0, 6         # Read float
         syscall
         add.s $f13, $f5, $f0     # f13 = B(input float)

hypotenuse:
    mul.s   $f12, $f12, $f12        # A*A
    mul.s   $f13, $f13, $f13        # B*B
    add.s   $f12, $f12, $f13        # A*A + B*B
    addi    $sp, $sp, -4            # Allocate
    sw  $ra 0($sp)

    add.s   $f0, $f12, $f12
    jal sqrt
    li  $v0, 3      # Print a Double    

    syscall         # Print the area
    lw  $ra 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4         # De-Allocate
    mov.s   $f0, $f12
    jr  $ra

sqrt:   add $v0, $zero, 0   # r := 0
loop:   mul $t0, $v0, $v0   # t0 := r*r
    bgt $t0, $a0, end   # if (r*r > n) goto end
    addi    $v0, $v0, 1 # r := r + 1
    j   loop        # goto loop
end:    addi    $v0, $v0, -1    # r := r - 1
    jr  $ra     # return with r-1 in $v0

# Exit
    li $v0, 10      # loads op code into $v0 to exit program
    syscall         # reads $v0 and exits program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sqrt` function returns a bogus value, because before you call it you calculate `A*A + B*B` in register `$f0`, but the function itself performs integer arithmetic on register `$v0`, which contains junk.